# Pass value of <select> tag in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Beginner question, but I'm trying to run a test to see how to pass the value of the selected option. Currently trying to console log the selected option's value, in this case value='2' or value='4'. Any advice or leads to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
testUpdate = selectedValue => {
    console.log(selectedValue);
};

render() {

    return (
        <select
            className='new-lead-dropdown'
            onChange={this.testUpdate}

            <option defaultValue value='1'>
                    Responses
            </option>
            <option value='2'>Phone</option>
            <option value='4'>Screen</option>
            <option value='5'>Interview</option>
            <option value='6'>Offer</option>
            <option value='15'>Hired</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Your select open tag is not closed. But regarding your question, What is the expected behaviour vs your actual results? An event param is passed in your `selectedValue`. you should be able to `selectedValue.target.value` to read the actual value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change,

`onChange={this.testUpdate}`

to

`onChange={e => this.testUpdate(e.target.value)}`

Here you need to make sure that you are passing down the selected value like [**e.target.value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) in `testUpdate` function.

> [**Working Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-box-with-onchange-r80i8)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

You have to grab the current event during `onChange` and retrieve the value. Hope this helps.

```
 <select onChange={(e) => this.testUpdate({ value: e.target.value })}>
    <option defaultValue value='1'>Responses
    <option value="2">Phone</option>
    <option value="4">Screen</option>
    <option value='5'>Interview</option>
    <option value="6">Offer</option>
    <option value="15">Hired</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
testUpdate = selectedValue => {
  console.log(selectedValue.target.value);
};
```